# Splitting text with tags using preg_split()

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to split the following text:

`<word>test</word><word>test2</word>`

etc via the following reg ex:

```
preg_split(":</?word>:is", $html);
```

I get the result: `test` and `test2` as the result, but what I need is to retrain the `<word>` and `</word>` tags, so instead of just test and test2, i get another 4 elements with the matching tags in them.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: use a parser to modify XML (something like `SimpleXML` of `DOM` could suit you fine, depending on the actions taken next).

However, for the sake of argument:

```
preg_split(":(</?word>):",
    "<word>test</word><word>test2</word>",
    0,
    PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: What's with the `is` modifiers; I'd give a vote if they weren't just copy/pasted from the question.

Comment: Ah, yes, wholly unnecessary indeed. I'll edit them out. (I do remember when starting out with regexes years ago  I typed `/six` almost per default :), at this moment I was just lazy c/p-ing of course... :P )

Comment: And here is your upvote, thank you for indulging a persnickity regex-author. :-)

Comment: @OZZIE: hence, focus on the first part of the answer (use something like `simpleXML` or `DOM`, or any other actual XML library...). And a background is linked in the other answer: https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Answer (score 0):

First off, [NEVER USE REGEX TO PARSE HTML](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)..

But to solve your problem, look at the flags for [`preg_split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
preg_split(
    ":(</?word>):is", 
    $html, 
    -1, 
    PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
);
```

Now, it'll split them and give you this:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "<word>"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "test"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "</word>"
  [3]=>
  string(2) ", "
  [4]=>
  string(6) "<word>"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "test2"
  [6]=>
  string(7) "</word>"
}
```

Still no good.  But, what we can do, is loop over the array, and move `<word>` to the next buffer, and `</word>` to the prior...

```
$buffer = '';
$newWords = array();
foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (strcasecmp($word, '<word>') === 0) {
        $buffer .= $word;
    } elseif (strcasecmp($word, '</word>') === 0) {
        // Find the last buffer
        $last = end($newWords);
        $newWords[key($newWords)] = $last . $buffer . $word;
        $buffer = '';
    } else {
        $newWords[] = $buffer . $word;
        $buffer = '';
    }
}
if (!empty($buffer)) {
    $newWords[] = $buffer;
}
```

Which would give you:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "<word>test</word>"
  [1]=>
  string(2) ", "
  [2]=>
  string(18) "<word>test2</word>"
}
```