# Regex split into array of pieces

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I was wondering how could I split this string

```
{{MENU}}<li><a href="{{LINK}}" title="{{TITLE}}"><span>{{TITLE}}</span></a></li>{{/MENU}}
```

Into array of:

```
array(
    "<li><a href=\"",
    "{{LINK}}",
    "\" title=\"",
    "{{TITLE}}",
    "\"><span>",
    "{{TITLE}}",
    "</span></a></li>"
)
```

It also should work with more different formats like:

```
{{MENU}}<a href="{{LINK}}" title="{{TITLE}}">{{TITLE}}</a>{{/MENU}}
{{MENU}}<b><a href="{{LINK}}" title="{{TITLE}}">{{TITLE}}</a></b>{{/MENU}}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to write this complex regex yet.

Comment: And I am wondering why you are not using a DOM Parser to get these values

Comment: Like Gordon said, although DOM Parser may sound a bit overwhelming... it's really what you need to use, as any kind of reg-ex will be a great deal of work and performance will suffer.

Comment: @Frederico actually, a Regex will perform faster, and I'm sure someone will come up with one for this specific case. It's just that a DOM Parser is more reliable, more generic and doesnt have to be taught to vaguely understand HTML first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with `preg_split()`

---

```
$yourArray = preg_split("/({{\w+}})/", $yourText, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

[The code](http://ideone.com/h41ub)

---

**Resources :**

- [php.net - preg_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

**On the same topic :**

- [Preg_split() help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418312/preg-split-help)

Comment: You need to put the pattern in parentheses.